# Was Empire Day still celebrated after the Fall of the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, empire

[Empire Day](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Empire_Day), a Galactic holiday celebrated the [23rd day of the **fifth month**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Empire_Day#Description) of the [Great ReSynchronization](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Great_ReSynchronization) calendar, was created during Palpatine's reign:

> In his declaration, Palpatine mandated that Imperial citizens would
>   celebrate the anniversary of Empire's creation yearly, for the sake of
>   posterity.

From same Wookieepedia article, on the celebration:

> Empire Day was celebrated in a number of different ways, depending on region and culture. Although the holiday fell on one specific day of the year, celebrations in some corners of the Empire continued for weeks.

After the fall of the Empire in 12 ABY, was this holiday still observed galaxy-wide?

Comment: Assuming the celebrations on Lothal are indicative, most people were cheering at gunpoint. When the Empire fell, I doubt they would have continued.

Comment: After the fall of the Empire there were still many pockets that had not heard the news or did not believe the news, so I guess these places could have still celebrated.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt it was observed galaxy-wide before the fall of the Empire, only in the areas the Empire still controlled. After, I would imagine it was still celebrated within the Imperial Remnant, because if holidays on Earth are any indication, people tend to celebrate holidays long after they've lost all of their original meaning or significance. All of that is just speculation, though.

According to Wookieepedia, the New Republic's [Remembrance Day](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Remembrance_Day) was celebrated on the same day as Empire Day, so perhaps that replaced Empire Day within the Republic.